# Analysis of emojis used in tweets with specific hashtags or keywords in R

Tags: r, twitter, emoji

I'd like to explore Twitter's API to do sentiment analysis via the emojis used in tweets containing certain keywords or hashtags. (Like what PRISMOJI do: https://twitter.com/PRISMOJI?s=09)

But I've never done this before - any pointers on the script?

I'm using rtweet to explore the API, but open to other tools - but hopefully in R.

UPDATE

So I've written some code and solved my original issue. Woop!)

```
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
insrall.packages("httpuv")
library(httpuv)


api_key <- 'api key entered here'

api_secret <- 'api secret entered here'

access_token <- 'token entered here'

access_token_secret <- 'key entered here'

token <- create_token(
  app = "my app name",
  consumer_key = api_key,
  consumer_secret = api_secret
  access_token = access_token,
  access_secret = access_token_secret)

tweets <- search_tweets(q ="#CleanDishwasher", n = 18000, include_rts = FAKSE, `-filter` = "replies", lang = "en")

## get coordinates associated with the following addresses/components

write_as_csv(tweets, "tweets.csv")

sydney <- lookup_coords("sydney", "country:AU")

## pass a returned coords object to search_tweets

sydney_tweets <- search_tweets(geocode = sydney)

##find top emojis
library(emo)
sydney_tweets %>%
  mutate(emoji = ji_extract_all(text)) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(emoji)) %>%
  count(emoji, sort = TRUE) %>%
  top_n(10)
```

Comment: Maybe take a look around the web at what approaches other folks are using? http://opiateforthemass.es/articles/emoji-analysis/ and https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/03/emojis-analysis-in-r/ and https://prismoji.com/2017/02/06/emoji-data-science-in-r-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks - great links!

Comment: Please see the update in my post at the top of this thread

Comment: It might be a good idea to write an answer to your question using your code and accept it. This way the question will be marked as answered and future readers can more easily see what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting my access keys and tokens, I had mistakenly used access_token_secret rather than access_secret.